# Will a battery bought in India work with a Canon T3i body bought in the US?

Tags: battery, canon-600d, international-differences

I live in India. My friend from the United States got me a Canon T3i during Thanksgiving in the US. But when the camera reached my hand, both the battery and the battery charger were missing (I suppose they may have been misplaced during customs check).

This is the battery  and charger for Canon 600D: *"Canon LC-E8 CBC-E8 Equivalent Charger for LP-E6 Digital Camera Battery"*

Can I buy the right battery and the charger in a Canon India showroom?

I'm concerned because the voltage output is different in India (220V) and the US (110V).

Comment: Most electronics of that sort are universal and auto-sensing, taking 100-240V at 50Hz or 60Hz; the only local difference (normally) is the mains cord (or plug module if it's meant to be used as a "wall wart"). The battery, in any case, would be the same.

Answer (score 2):

In US you get different power adapter to convert voltage and in India another. So it`s completely safe to get camera in one country and battery and charger in another.

Comment: In fact, sounds like you'd want a local charger _anyway_, right?

Comment: @mattdm it depends what 'local charger' means to you. People in US have add-on for charger to use electric power, and people from well from rest of the world have standard chargers :)

Comment: AFAIK, All Nikon chargers are universal chargers and can adapt to any voltage, I believe Canon should be same too!

Answer (score 1):

*Stan Rogers* is right, both battery and the charger are usually universal, you may just need a different cord and plug. but as the whole thing is missing, you shouldn't have any problem. just contact Canon India and ask them, they can help you better: http://www.canon.co.in/business/web/contact